# How can you query begins_with for primary keys in DynamoDB?

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

What's the best way to filter results with the begins_with method for boto3.dynamodb.condition.Key?

```
import boto3
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb.Table('MyTable')
response = table.query(KeyConditionExpression=Key('myPrimaryKey').begins_with('americas'))
```

The results, although conditions supports begins_with, is the query is not supported. Can you not use begins_with on primary or sort keys?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Primary keys in DynamoDB can be either *simple* or *composite*.

**Simple** primary keys are consist of a partition key and *no* sort key.

**Composite** primary keys have both a partition key *and* a sort key.

You can only use `begins_with` on the sort key, *not* the partition key.

Comment: What would be the best approach here then to filter for a specific attribute in a table that begins_with where you don't have the partition/sort keys? scan() with a ScanFilter?

Comment: Actually, I think I see the error. I switched to table.scan(FilterExpression=Attr('myotherattribute').begins_with('S')) and it returns no results. I verified the records exist in the table. When I search other records that have different schemas in the same table. I get results. When I just scan the entire table with no filters, I see all the records BUT the ones I want to filter for. Why are they hidden in scan table, but clearly showing in the AWS console?

Comment: Ahh, the scan response is limited. I was right, just need to page the results. Thanks for the help Seth. I'll mark this as complete as you cannot filter primary key with begins_with. I used the table.scan(FilterExpression=Attr().begins_with() on another attribute, then paged the results LastEvaluatedKey existing or not.

Comment: This particular area of DynamoDB can be tricky. The scan operation is powerful, allowing you to search across any attribute.  Paired with filtering, you can implement most access patterns you're after.  However, be mindful of how you are using the `scan` operation.  It searches the entire database to fetch what you are after, as opposed to a specific `getItem` or `query` operation that offers a more performant solution.

Comment: Filtering is another thing that can be confusing.  Keep in mind that DynamoDB reads up to 1MB of data from the table, applies any filters, then returns a response.  This can result in a scenario where `scan` returns several pages of empty responses before you hit the responses you are expecting. Filters, like the `scan` operation, are powerful but can produce results that are not what one may expect.

Comment: What would be a better option? The documentation is not clear. I essentially want to filter for 5 records out of 25k where an attribute is not null (or exists)?

Comment: Fetching 5 items out of 25k using `scan` will require DynamoDB to check every single of one of the 25k records to find the 5 you're after.

I don't know the specifics of your access pattern, but you could use a global secondary index (GSI) to fetch items based on whether or not a specific attribute exists.  You could do this by defining a GSI and setting it's partition key to the attribute you are currently filtering on.  If an item has that attribute set, it'll be in the index.  If it doesn't, it wont be in the index.  Look up the sparse index pattern for DDB, it's a common approach.

Comment: https://www.trek10.com/blog/best-practices-for-secondary-indexes-with-dynamodb